# Gratitude without knowing for who?

Tags: metaethics, human-condition

Is it possible to have gratitude without a source? A simple example would be can an atheist have gratitude towards no one for the circumstances he finds himself in? I think I'm presupposing a human condition which enables
ones to say if such a stance is possible? Which philosophers should I add to my reading list for this notion of gratitude (assuming it exists)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by source. If you mean an immediate act of kindness or luck in favor of something large an extract like "the wonders of existence", then absolutely. [Gratitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratitude) is simply an emotion and there's no reason it can't be a response to any object, including the eventual loss of one's own life. From WP:

> Gratitude, thankfulness or gratefulness, from the Latin word gratus, meaning "pleasing" or "thankful",[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratitude) is regarded as a feeling of appreciation (or similar positive response) by a recipient of another's kindness,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_eusociality)[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociobiology) gifts, help, favours, or other form of generosity[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism) to the giver of such gifts.[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_psychology) Historically, gratitude has been a part of several world religions.[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behaviorism) It also has been a topic of interest to ancient, medieval, and modern philosophers.[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_psychology)

From a [naturalized epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalized_epistemology), gratitude is a eusocial behavior and can be explained in terms of the [evolution of eusociality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_eusociality). [Sociobiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociobiology) is the academic discipline founded by Edward O. Wilson which seeks to partially reduce the theory of [psychological altruism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism) to ultimately biological principles like Darwin's theory of natural selection and anatomical and physiological structures. In essence, emotions might be viewed through the lens of a [control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_system) to ensure survival of the species through forms of cooperation and collaboration. Frans de Waal has written a number of books on Chimpanzees to show how closely Great Ape behavior resembles human behavior.

In the [philosophy of psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_psychology) there have been radical shifts from the [behaviorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behaviorism) of the early 20th century, to [anti-psychiatry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-psychiatry) and [positive psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_psychology) of the latter half of the 20th. Any philosopher of the mind would be keen to note that explanations about aberrant human behavior have stricken an arc from demonic possession to [folk psychologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_psychology) based on Freudian pseudoscientific notions to detailed positions based on fMRIs and contemporary [cognitive science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science). I think it's fair to say that Seligman's [*Authentic Happiness*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Authentic_Happiness/Fov5vQAACAAJ?hl=en) builds an entire prescription for gratitude based on a philosophy of mind that places the [locus of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_of_control) of one's emotions and mood squarely within the individual. In fact, that may even challenge your philosophical notions about mind, as many people maintain a certain degree of helplessness in their [propositional attitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_attitude) regarding self-control. In fact, some psychologists posit that [learned helplessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learned_helplessness), which would be characterized as a series of propositional attitudes and thus are [metaphysical claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) in nature, are responsible for bodily ailments like dysthymia and depression. Ultimately, since the [mind-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_problem) rears its head, such claims can be philosophically contentious.

Comment: Haha ... indeed. I thought it was unethical to say one was right over the others (and thought some might get offended) so I stopped using it. But if its taken in the right spirit sure!

Comment: You mention "evolution of eusociality" but if this was evolutionary reasons surely it would make sense to attribute the gratitude to someone/something? Also a philosophy which explicitly articulates gratitude without requiring a source/(even within the individual) would be welcome as and example?

Comment: First, there are 8 billion people. Your mere existence offends probably more people you can count for more reasons than you know. Be your best self, but don't apologize for being you or thinking your thoughts. You are entitled to exist and conclude. As an athiest, some people loathe my existence and many more my arguments. 2nd, is prescient to declare that there is an original object of gratitude,  and that would be sacrifice. When others sacrifice for us, we reciprocate. But cognition is flexible.  That's the backbone of general intelligence that computers and chimps lack....

Comment: So, by evolution sexuality was driven by the need for genetic recombination.   But that human arousal is flexible is a function of general intelligence. Now, human sexuality can be predicated upon just any object you can imagine. We call these fetishes...

Comment: According to Gould, incidental features are called spandrels. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandrel_%28biology%29?wprov=sfla1

Comment: It might be helpful to see general intelligence and the ability to have conceptualization a spandrel of sorts if you don't buy the argument that general intelligence and linguistic faculty is selected for.

Comment: It would help if you consider how language shapes intuition through theory-laden presumption. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Thus, our private realities are a function of our culture and language,  a notion known as social constructionism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructionism?wprov=sfla1